# How do I prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{b-1} [k \frac{a}{b}] = \frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be relatively prime positive integers.

Then, how do I prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{b-1} [k \frac{a}{b}] = \frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$?

Please give me some hints..

Comment: What is $[k\frac{a}{b}]$?Is it a floor function?

Comment: @rogerl: care to explain? I calculate $1$ on both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

This sum comes up
in Gauss' proof of
the law of quadratic reciprocity.

Eisenstein's nice geometric proof
is in many places;
here is one:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity

Comment: Are you sure? Because I don't think the equation is valid as stated.

Comment: I looked at the link again and it seems to match OP's result. Have you checked it?

Comment: You are correct; my counterexample was the result of miscalculation on my part. I love Eisenstein's proof, by the way; I used it in a class a few years back.