# Prove $\sum_{0<x<\frac{b}{2}}\lfloor{\frac{ax}{b}}\rfloor + \sum_{0<y<\frac{a}{2}}\lfloor{\frac{by}{a}}\rfloor=\frac{(a-1)}{2}\frac{(b-1)}{2}$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, with $a,b$ odd and coprime. I need to prove $$\sum_{0<x<\frac{b}{2}}\lfloor{\frac{ax}{b}}\rfloor + \sum_{0<y<\frac{a}{2}}\lfloor{\frac{by}{a}}\rfloor=\frac{(a-1)}{2}\frac{(b-1)}{2}.$$
To do this, I've written $a=2m+1,b=2n+1$, from which follows that $\frac{(a-1)}{2}\frac{(b-1)}{2}=m\cdot n$.
I rewrote the original problem to become
$$\sum^m_{x=0}\lfloor{\frac{ax}{b}}\rfloor + \sum^n_{y=0}\lfloor{\frac{by}{a}}\rfloor=m\cdot n.$$
Furthermore, I've stumbled upon a lemma in my book which says that for $c,d$ coprime,
$$\sum^{d-1}_{j=0}\lfloor\frac{cj}{d}\rfloor=\frac{(c-1)(d-1)}{2}.$$
How can I use this to solve my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove an Elementary sum of floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779135/prove-an-elementary-sum-of-floor-function) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7B0%5Clt%20x%5Clt%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Clfloor%7B%5Cfrac%7Bax%7D%7Bb%7D%7D%5Crfloor%2B%5Csum_%7B0%5Clt%20y%5Clt%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Clfloor%7B%5Cfrac%7Bby%7D%7Ba%7D%7D%5Crfloor%3D%5Cfrac%7B(a-1)%7D%7B2%7D%5Cfrac%7B(b-1)%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1). Note another duplicate is [Give me some hints to prove this](/q/3948386). There's also ...

Comment: (cont.) the AoPS thread [Help me with this problem, please! =)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2180610p16307127), where your question is its problem II, but there's no current answer to it there.